# Unload MovieClip before Removing?

Tags: flash, garbage-collection, actionscript-2, movieclip

Is it better to `Unload` a MovieClip **before** `Removing` it off the Stage, in order for its contents to get cleared from RAM and therefore free up RAM better?

Adobe Flash AS2 Documentation:

- **`removeMovieClip()`** - Removes a movie clip instance.
- **`unloadMovie()`** - Removes the contents of a movie clip instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. According to the [Live Docs:](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/mx2004/main_7_2/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Flash_MX_2004&file=00001563.html)

> `unloadMovieClip` removes the contents
>   of a movie clip instance. **The
>   instance properties and clip handlers
>   remain.**
>
> To **remove the instance, including
>   its properties and clip handlers**,
>   use `MovieClip.removeMovieClip().`

This means `removeMovieClip()` will remove all traces of a `MovieClip` instance, while `unloadMovieClip()` will only remove the contents of it. It also means `unloadMovie()` is not necessary to call before calling `removeMovieClip()`.

Answer (score 4):

As much as I hate to say this.
removeMovieClip DOES NOT remove all traces of a movieclip.
For instance: if setInterval is used it will fire an event even after unloading or removing the movieclip (as I had to find out the hard way)

Answer (score 0):

A removeMovieClip does an explicit unloadMovieClip (if necessary). However, unloading a clip does not remove the instance.

Comment: If necessary? Whats the criteria. Is it better to Unload a MovieClip before Removing it off the Stage?

Comment: I think Luke meant to say "implicit", or perhaps "automatic". The unloading is done automatically by removeMovieClip() if the MovieClip has any contents. If not, there's no need to unload it.